# Rooted Motorola Moto G 2014 xt1068 OTA always loads up TWRP

Tags: twrp, motorola

I've rooted my Motorola Moto G 2014, it`s using a standard ROM (I think).
Today I got a notification about the OTA update to lollipop so naively clicked it. It downloaded and then when it came to rebooting it turned off and booted into TWRP.
Every time I turn it off in TWRP then attempt to turn it back on again it gets to the unlock screen then powers off again and loads up TWRP...

How do I save my phone because its just repeating that process... is there any way to get it  not to go into TWRP and instead load whatever is meant to load to update the phone?

Comment: You will probably need to flash the stock recovery to finish the update process.

Comment: If you know where the stuff was downloaded to (I can't tell), there should be ways to delete that from within TWRP.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this exact problem with a Moto G 2015. [TWRP themselves warn not to install OTA updates with TWRP](https://twrp.me/faq/officialota.html). Here's what I did:

1. [Install the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk) or [download fastboot separately](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934532795)
2. Get the build number for your phone

   1. From TWRP on your phone go to *Mount* and make sure *System* is selected
   2. Connect your phone to your computer and open build.prop with a text editor
   3. The build number is on the line beginning with `ro.build.id=`
3. Download the stock ROM for that build number and unzip it
4. From TWRP on your phone go to *Reboot* → *Bootloader*
5. Flash the factory recovery

   ```
   sudo /path/to/fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
   ```
6. Use the volume buttons to select the option to boot the phone. It should then install the OTA update successfully.

Next time you can save yourself some time by flashing the stock recovery ahead of time.

If the update fails for any reason after that point, it's normally because other files have been modified and the checksum failed. You can normally look at `/cache/recovery/last_log` to see which file is causing the problem and replace it with stock. More details on that here:

[Moto G OTA update error](http://laviefrugale.blogspot.ca/2015/05/moto-g-ota-update-error.html)

Comment: I downloaded the stock ROM, but there doesn't seem to be a file named recovery.img (I only found boot.img)

Comment: I've never seen a stock rom that didn't have recovery.img. Which ROM did you download? I typically get mine from here: http://www.filefactory.com/folder/c6cdedc45a775d27

Comment: I got it from here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/how-to/fxz-flashable-stock-npjs25-93-14-4-t3623010/page2

Comment: From the [first post in that thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=72702348&postcount=1): "The zip contains all parts of a full stock ROM EXCEPT for the BOOTLOADER, PARTITION TABLE and STOCK RECOVERY"